# Why calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) return 31 instead of 30?

Tags: java

Why I'm getting 31 instead of 3? Now December, so previous of Nov = 30.

```
Calendar calendarPreviousMonth = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendarPreviousMonth.add(Calendar.MONTH, calendarCurrent.get(Calendar.MONTH) - 1);
        System.out.println("Amount of days in month " + calendarPreviousMonth.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

Thank you!

Comment: You're looking at the *previous* month (Nov), aren't you?

Comment: Yes, I'm. Sorry, corrected a question.

Comment: Add descriptive comments to your code. You will get great answers for a better described question.

Comment: I suspect it's still November in the time zone for which your calendar is configured, so it's giving you the number of days in October.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Code to find last month should be following:

```
calendarPreviousMonth.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
calendarPreviousMonth.add(Calendar.MONTH, calendarCurrent.get(Calendar.MONTH)-1)
```

You either want to add `-1` to month or set it to `calendarCurrent.get(Calendar.MONTH) - 1`. Not both! Try this:

```
calendarPreviousMonth.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
```

**or** this:

```
calendarPreviousMonth.set(Calendar.MONTH, calendarCurrent.get(Calendar.MONTH)-1)
```